# CentOs 6.9 Mysqld failed to start (InnoDB Error: innodb_system data file './ibdata1' is of a different size)

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, vps

Upgraded to php 5.5 (I KNOW ITS OLD) and updated my phpMyAdmin version, aswell as MySQL to 5.7, and now MySQL wont start...

Looking in the mysqld log:
`2018-03-16T16:35:54.553247Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The Auto-extending innodb_system data file './ibdata1' is of a different size 640 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file: initial 768 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
2018-03-16T16:35:54.553310Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2018-03-16T16:35:55.153859Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-03-16T16:35:55.153924Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-03-16T16:35:55.153944Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2018-03-16T16:35:55.153964Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting`

Can someone please make me aware as to why this may be happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration file /etc/my.cnf contains an innodb_xxxx that refers to an autoextend with size of 768 pages. This can include paramaters like

innodb_data_home_dir

innodb_data_file_path

The full syntax describes this value

```
file_name:file_size[:autoextend[:max:max_file_size]]
```

Example

```
innodb_data_file_path=/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1:768M:autoextend
```

If you have access to the previous working MySQL (like another server of your friend), login to the mysql client and type following to view the running configuration

```
> SELECT @@GLOBAL.innodb_data_file_path;

+--------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.innodb_data_file_path |
+--------------------------------+
| ibdata1:10M:autoextend         |
+--------------------------------+
```

## Why this is happening?

You have an existing innodb storage file that is smaller than the initial size specified in your my.cnf configuration.

Hope this clarify matters.

Answer (score 2):

For future users this is my experience:

I faced the same error and the problem was my local volume didn't exist.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mysql-db:
    image: mariadb:10.8
    container_name: mysql-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4407:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql/
```

the folder `./db` did not exist.

after I made the folder in the current path, it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I followzed your advice and work out a solution, that's about 2 lines in bash, and there you are. I saw the following message upon starting up some mysql/mariadb server or docker image :

> The Auto-extending innodb_system data file './ibdata1' is of a
>   different size 0 pages than specified in the .cnf file: initial 768
>   pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!

Then a previous installation's been detected and the data file space is incompatible. A simple straightforward solution's to remove exisiting container images that may be backed up on the host. Quickstart the Docker `rmi` command is ready to achieve a clean but irreversible action, you're supposed to know what's the name of your docker image, e.g. mariadb:

```
docker rmi `docker images | grep mariadb | awk '{print $3}'`
```

Retry run the new mysql image :

```
docker run -it mypersonalrepo/mariadb:latest &
```

The database will be initialized with InnoDB 768M data of space.